# Эмулятор в Android Studio запускает старую версию проекта

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

Проблема заключается в следующем: в какой-то момент android studio при запуске проекта стал запускать его старую версию, т.е. какие бы изменения я бы ни вносил в код или ресурсы проекта, запускается все равно та же самая конфигурация, что была в момент возникновения бага. Причем никаких специфичных действий в этот момент не производил - исправлял ошибку, работал только с кодом. В дальнейшем этот же код полностью вычистил, даже пытался переключиться на другой Activity, но безрезультатно.

Comment: Скорее всего вам поможет отключение `InstantRun` в настройках

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то попробуйте очистить проект и пересобрать.

- Build -> Clean Project
- Build -> Rebuild Project

**Обновление**

Да, много ошибок. Если в Вашем коде не может быть ошибок, я бы попробовал удалить настройки студии или заново переустановил.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не могу зайти через как автор вопроса. Я смог решить задачу, для этого я обновил модуль HAXM, который android studio настоятельно мне рекомендовал обновить, однако я не придавал этому особого внимания. После этого все запустилось, а ошибки исчезли. Вопрос исчерпан.